# Rasa, Botfront and heroku: Frontend doesn't work after deployment

Tags: python, docker, heroku, rasa

I have deployed my rasa chatbot online by creating a docker image, pushing and releasing it to Heroku. Now my bot is live on Heroku. I would like to communicate with this bot, through my website. I have added my bot url to Botfront widget's socketurl. However, when I send a message, I do not get any response. Does anyone know what I'm missing or doing wrong?

The content of my script is:

```
      <!-- chatbot -->
      <script>
        !(function () {
          let e = document.createElement("script"),
            t = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
          (e.src = "{% static 'js/chatbot.js' %}"),
            (e.async = !0),
            (e.onload = () => {
              window.WebChat.default(
                {
                  customData: { language: "en" },
                  socketUrl: "https://app-name.herokuapp.com",//not real bot url
                  // add other props here
                  // initPayload: "/greet",
                  title: "Let's talk, we are online.",
                  subtitle: "Say hi to get started.",
                },
                null
              );
            }),
            t.insertBefore(e, t.firstChild);
        })();
      </script>
```

If someone can help me, I would really appreciate it, been stuck on this for days!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the SocketIO configuration? You should add the following in your `credentials.yml` file (it will be inside your Docket container, not in `git` repository).

```
socketio:
  user_message_evt: user_uttered
  bot_message_evt: bot_uttered
  session_persistence: true # or false
```

You can see more details in [RASA documentation for web channel](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/your-own-website/#websocket-channel).

Comment: Did that but no promising results

Answer (score 0):

I see, since Heroku is using python as server end it might be not able to load index.html or any HTML code. try hosting your HTML code to a different server. I would suggest using Github's profile hosting. 
I have also hosted my HTML page on GitHub and rasa server on a cloud server.
check it out here: https://horizon733.github.io/

Also, check out this documentation by [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally) while using the python server.
I hope this helps, feel free to ask any doubts.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.